# Fatal error: Call to a member function extend() on boolean in /var/www/html/mage/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 600

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error, local.xml

I am trying to tranfer magento from server to localhost,
but it is giving

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function extend() on boolean in /var/www/html/mage/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 600
```

this error

local.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Core
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2017 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
-->
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date><![CDATA[Fri, 09 Jun 2017 09:16:23 +0000]]></date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
            <key><![CDATA[5f2d5e63de2cea16e028b34496eb4a40]]></key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[bs_]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
                     <username><![CDATA[vinay]]></username>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[mage]]></dbname>
                    <password><![CDATA[PD9@wzmnhun31]]></password>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Comment: Has your xml got a space at the start like your example?

Comment: where is the space in my example

Comment: At the start of your xml